# How to make grid elements horizontally to vertically aligned when mobile orientation changed with JQuery Mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a simple JQuery Mobile web page where a grid has four blocks horizontally aligned. Each block has a some text description and a button.

It is shown well on a desktop browser while the blocks look pretty squeezy when shown on my android galaxy phone as they are still horizontally aligned.

How can I configure or style the grid to automatically align the blocks vertically when screen is orientated from portrait to landscape?

```
<div id="grid1" class="ui-grid-c">
                <div class="ui-block-a">
                    <div class="div-widget" id="divEnterObs">
                        <h2>Enter Observations</h2>
                        <span>View and enter observations by map or form.</span>
                        <a data-ajax="false" href="LocationlistingServlet"
                            data-role="button" id="btnEnterObs" data-theme="a" data-corners="true" data-shadow="true"
                            data-inline="false" data-mini="false">
                            Enter Observations</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="ui-block-b">
                    <div class="div-widget" id="divManageUserAccess">
                        <h2>Manage user access</h2>
                        <span>Manage and appoint members that can access the app.</span>
                        <a data-ajax="false" href="manageUserAccess.jsp"
                            data-role="button" id="btnManageUserAccess" data-theme="a" data-corners="true" data-shadow="true"
                            data-inline="false" data-mini="false">
                            Manage User Access</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="ui-block-c">
                    <div class="div-widget" id="divManageLocations">
                        <h2>Manage locations</h2>
                        <span>Add, update or activate / de-activate locations.</span>
                        <a data-ajax="false" href="#"
                            data-role="button" id="btnManageLocations" data-theme="a" data-corners="true" data-shadow="true"
                            data-inline="false" data-mini="false">
                            Manage Locations</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="ui-block-d">
                    <div class="div-widget" id="divAdminTools">
                        <h2>Admin Tools</h2>
                        <span>Execute admin functions.</span>
                        <a data-ajax="false" href="#"
                            data-role="button" id="btnAdminTools" data-theme="a" data-corners="true" data-shadow="true"
                            data-inline="false" data-mini="false">
                            Admin Tools</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can add css media queries as in this example: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/grids-custom-responsive/

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved as such by adding "ui-responsive".

```
<div id="grid1" class="ui-grid-c ui-responsive">
```